# pygame.colliderect moving rectangles

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to write a pacman clone using pygame. I have a ghost and our pacman moving around the maze and I tried to define a function that would recognise whether they collided and change the variable which tells whether the game is supposed to go on.

This is the function:

```
def eat(self, pacman):
    if self.rect.colliderect(pacman):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

And this is game loop:

```
while (game_on == True):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
    pacman.change_direction(tiles)
    ghost.Move(tiles, layout)
    for tile in tiles:
        pacman.collision(tile)
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    for tile in tiles:
        tile.draw(screen)
    ghost.draw(screen)
    pacman.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    game_on = ghost.eat(pacman)

if game_on is False:
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    text = font.render('GAME OVER', True, (255,255,0))
    screen.blit(text, SCREEN_SIZE)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Both pacman and ghost are classes with self.rect that is a pygame.Rect
Same method to check collision works just fine for ghost and maze tiles; here they just go through each other.

Comment: I don't have any insight on why your collision test isn't working, but some general code quality suggestions: Instead of `return False` and `return True` in `eat`, you can just do `return not self.rect.colliderect(pacman)`. Your `while` condition can just be `game_on` (no need for `== True`). Similarly, the `if` at the end should just be `if not game_on` instead of testing specifically for `False`.

Comment: Thanks for advices, I'm still learning python.
The questions still remains though.

Answer (score 1):

You were giving your `eat()` function the whole `pacman` class for collision detection. Use `pacman.rect` instead.

Example: Instead of `game_on = ghost.eat(pacman)`, use `game_on = ghost.eat(pacman.rect)`.

Comment: @Malcadicta This answer should fix your problem unless the problem lies within code you haven't shared with us. One possible reason is that you don't move the ghost's rect and pacman's along with their positions. You claim that the same technique works in the `collision` method, but in that case this answer should work. Could you edit your answer to include the Pacman and Ghost class?